# SQLAlchemy SELECT WITH clause/statement (pgsql)

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, common-table-expression

How would one execute a SQL query that uses `WITH` in sqlalchemy?

```
WITH foo AS (...), bar as (...) SELECT (...)
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html

Using postgres.

Comment: Take a look at [`sqlalchemy.orm.Query.cte(...)`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.cte)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This piece of code from the author of SQLAlchemy in [this email thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/8R-clEbJUCI) might be of help

```
q1 = s.query(distinct(Appl.refid), Appl).\ 
        filter(Appl.lastname.ilike('Williamson%')).\ 
        filter(Appl.firstname.ilike('d%')).\ 
        group_by(Appl).\ 
        order_by(Appl.refid, Appl.appldate.desc()) 

q1 = q1.cte('distinct_query') 
q2 = s.query(q1).order_by(q1.c.lastname, q1.c.firstname) 
q2.all()
```

outputs as:

```
WITH distinct_query AS 
(SELECT DISTINCT appl.refid AS anon_1, appl.id AS id, appl.firstname AS     firstname, appl.lastname AS lastname, appl.refid AS refid, appl.appldate AS appldate 
FROM appl 
WHERE appl.lastname ILIKE %(lastname_1)s AND appl.firstname ILIKE %(firstname_1)s GROUP BY appl.id, appl.firstname, appl.lastname, appl.refid, appl.appldate ORDER BY appl.refid, appl.appldate DESC) 
 SELECT distinct_query.anon_1 AS distinct_query_anon_1, distinct_query.id AS distinct_query_id, distinct_query.firstname AS distinct_query_firstname, distinct_query.lastname AS distinct_query_lastname, distinct_query.refid AS distinct_query_refid, distinct_query.appldate AS distinct_query_appldate 
FROM distinct_query ORDER BY distinct_query.lastname, distinct_query.firstname
```